# Probability of finding a non-repeating combination

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

This is a real life problem, which I'm turning into balls just to make it easier to understand.

Suppose balls can be numbered from 1 to 12.

Suppose I have 10 boxes. Each box has 3 distinct balls, distributed at random.

A valid combination is if I can find, from those 10 boxes and taking 1 ball from each, a combination where all balls have distinct numbers (i.e. there are (12,10) valid combinations).

Here are some examples, to make it more concrete:

- Box 1 has (1,2,3), Box 2 has (2,3,4), Box 3 has (3,4,5)... Box 10 has (10,11,12). This is the best case scenario, I can easily make valid combinations such as (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10); (1,2,3,..,9,11); and so on
- Box 1 has (1,2,3), Box 2 has (1,2,3), Box 3 has (1,2,3), Box 4 has (1,2,3). This is the worst case scenario, as I can't find any valid combination. I will always have to repeat 1, 2 or 3.

I would like to know what is the probability of finding scenarios that yield valid combinations from such a setup. In other words - given a scenario of 10 box with 3 distinct balls in each, what is the probability that from those 10 boxes I can find at least one valid combination (it doesn't matter if there is more than 1 valid combination).

Here's a potential approach:

The universe of potential combinations: A = C(12,3)^10

The cases where numbers repeat and I get an invalid scenario:

B = C(12,9) * C(9,3)^10

Probability is then 1 - B/A.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I think the question is precise (i.e. all info is there), and I don't have further thoughts on the problem (I'm really stuck on even how to approach it); I started to think I should even try the brute force approach, but I suppose there is an analytical solution to this problem (I'm really rusty at maths).

Comment: I do not think the problem is clearly state either. On one hand you say, there are balls numbered $1$ to $12$. Then you say $3$ distinct balls in each of the $10$ boxes. That makes it $30$ balls. On what basis, these $30$ balls are numbered? Random?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned distributed at random there; the only restriction is that within each box, the balls are distinct.

Comment: I added 2 examples for best and worst case; and I refined the question to the probability of finding scenarios that yield valid combinations. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Personally, although I normally want the OP to show work, it somewhat depends on the nature of the query.  For this query, I do think that it would be reasonable for someone to offer a constructive hint, if they have one.

Comment: I think that the problem is complex and I have two ideas that may or may not help.  [1] I would strive to express the probability as $$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}},$$ where $$D = \binom{12}{3}^{(10)}.$$ [2] I would explore **recursion**, manually examining the case of (first) $4$ boxes, then $5$ boxes, $\cdots$.  I would try to find a pattern in the enumeration between $n$ boxes and $(n+1)$ boxes.  **Unclear** if this 2nd idea will go anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a simpler case: 4 boxes and balls numbered from 1 to 6. We still put 3 balls in each box. I have chosen this case, since it is possible to write out all combinations and check corresponding probabilities.

For each box, we now have $6\choose3$ possible combinations.

In the first box, we can select any ball, yielding a probability of 1.
For the second box, we have two options to select a valid ball (i.e. a ball not selected previously):

- A box without the ball that we already selected. The total number of possibilities for this case are ${1\choose0}{5\choose3}$. ${1\choose0}$ specifies the number of balls we select from the previously selected balls. ${5\choose3}$ specifies the number of combinations of choosing three balls from the remaining five that have not been selected previously. The probability of selecting a valid ball is 1, since the previously selected ball is not in the box.
- A box with the ball that we already have selected. Out of the $6\choose3$ possibilities, ${1\choose1}{5\choose2}$ have the already selected ball. Selecting a valid ball has a probability of $\frac{2}{3}$.

Thus, selecting a valid ball from the second box is given by $\frac{1\times {1\choose0}{5\choose3} + \frac{2}{3}\times{1\choose1}{5\choose2}}{6\choose3} = \frac{5}{6}$.

For the third box, we have the following cases:

- A box without the previously selected balls: ${2\choose0}{4\choose3}$ possibilities. The probability of selecting a valid ball is 1.
- A box with one previously selected ball: ${2\choose1} {4\choose2}$. The probability of selecting a valid ball is $\frac{2}{3}$.
- A box with two previously selected balls: ${2\choose2}{4\choose1}$ possibilities, with a probability of $\frac{1}{3}$ of not selecting a previously selected ball.

For the third box, the probability of selecting a valid ball is consequently:
$\frac{1 \times {2\choose0}{4\choose3} + \frac{2}{3} \times {2\choose1} {4\choose2} + \frac{1}{3}\times {2\choose2}{4\choose1}}{6\choose3} = \frac{4}{6}$.

For the fourth box, we have the following cases:

- No previously selected balls: ${3\choose0}{3\choose3}$ possibilities. We have a probability of 1 of selecting a valid ball.
- One previously selected ball: ${3\choose1}{3\choose2}$. Corresponding probability is $\frac{2}{3}$.
- Two previously selected balls: ${3\choose2}{3\choose1}$. Corresponding probability is $\frac{1}{3}$.
- Three previously selected balls: ${3\choose3}{3\choose0}$. Corresponding probability is 0.

For the fourth box, the probability of selecting a valid ball is thus given by:
$\frac{1 \times {3\choose0}{3\choose3} + \frac{2}{3}\times {3\choose1}{3\choose2} + \frac{1}{3} \times {3\choose2}{3\choose1} + 0 \times {3\choose3}{3\choose0}}{6\choose3} = \frac{3}{6}$.

We thus find the probability of valid combinations for this scenario as follows:
$\text{P(selected balls are distinct)} = \frac{6}{6}\times\frac{5}{6}\times\frac{4}{6}\times\frac{3}{6} = \frac{\frac{6!}{(6-4)!}}{6^4}$.

This pattern also arises in your scenario. In your scenario, we find a probability of:
$\text{P(Selected balls are all distinct)} = \frac{\frac{12!}{(12-10)!}}{12^{10}}\approx 0.003868$.